# Probable issue with LSTM in lasagne

Tags: machine-learning, lstm, lasagne

With a simple constructor for the LSTM, as given in the tutorial, and an input of dimension [*,*,1] one would expect to see an output of shape [*,*,num_units]. 
But regardless of the num_units passed during construction, the output has the same shape as the input.

Following is the min code to replicate this issue...

```
    import lasagne
    import theano
    import theano.tensor as T
    import numpy as np

    num_batches= 20
    sequence_length= 100
    data_dim= 1
    train_data_3= np.random.rand(num_batches,sequence_length,data_dim).astype(theano.config.floatX)

    #As in the tutorial
    forget_gate = lasagne.layers.Gate(b=lasagne.init.Constant(5.0))
    l_lstm = lasagne.layers.LSTMLayer(
                                     (num_batches,sequence_length, data_dim), 
                                     num_units=8,
                                     forgetgate=forget_gate
                                     )

    lstm_in= T.tensor3(name='x', dtype=theano.config.floatX)

    lstm_out = lasagne.layers.get_output(l_lstm, {l_lstm:lstm_in})
    f = theano.function([lstm_in], lstm_out)
    lstm_output_np= f(train_data_3)

    lstm_output_np.shape
    #= (20, 100, 1)
```

An unqualified LSTM (I mean in its default mode) should produce one output for each unit right?
The code was run on kaixhin's cuda lasagne docker image  [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/kaixhin/cuda-lasagne/)
What gives? 
Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can fix that by using a lasagne.layers.InputLayer

```
import lasagne
import theano
import theano.tensor as T
import numpy as np

num_batches= 20
sequence_length= 100 
data_dim= 1
train_data_3= np.random.rand(num_batches,sequence_length,data_dim).astype(theano.config.floatX)

#As in the tutorial
forget_gate = lasagne.layers.Gate(b=lasagne.init.Constant(5.0))
input_layer = lasagne.layers.InputLayer(shape=(num_batches, # <-- change
              sequence_length, data_dim),)  # <-- change
l_lstm = lasagne.layers.LSTMLayer(input_layer,  # <-- change
                                 num_units=8,
                                 forgetgate=forget_gate
                                 )

lstm_in= T.tensor3(name='x', dtype=theano.config.floatX)

lstm_out = lasagne.layers.get_output(l_lstm, lstm_in)  # <-- change
f = theano.function([lstm_in], lstm_out)
lstm_output_np= f(train_data_3)

print lstm_output_np.shape
```

If you feed your input into the input_layer, it is not ambiguous anymore, so you do not even need to specify where the input is supposed to go. Directly specifying a shape and adding the tensor3 into the LSTM does not work.